# SQL - Error: INSERT INTO Table

Tags: php, sql, database, insert

I can't figure out what's causing this insert error for the life of me. It should just be a simple insert, but no matter what I do or change it won't accept it. I've verified the syntax at multiple sources, and it seems fine.

Database and table both print success messages too.

Code below:

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db_test";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Database created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error creating database: " . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
mysql_select_db(db_test, $conn);
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table (
ID INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,)";
// create variables
$full_name=$_POST['full_name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
//Execute the query
$sql = "INSERT INTO 'test_table' (ID, Name, Email)
            VALUES('NULL', '$full_name' , '$email')";
            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: don't you want to execute `if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)` for the `CREATE TABLE` syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Within your posted code following are errors:

1.You close the connection after creating database and then select database. `$conn->close();` which is allowed.

2.Syntax error at selecting database `mysql_select_db(db_test, $conn);`.

3.You do not execute the create table `$sql` query.

4.You set the table field `ID` as `NULL` which is `Primary key` of your table.
Hope it works....

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db_test";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Database created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error creating database: " . $conn->error;
}
//select database
mysql_select_db($conn,'db_test');
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table (
ID INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)";
//create table
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "table created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error creating tabel: " . $conn->error;
}
// create variables
$full_name=$_POST['full_name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
//Execute the query
$sql = "INSERT INTO test_table (Name, Email)
            VALUES('$full_name' , '$email')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There should not be quote around the table name in the query, so right query will be -

```
INSERT INTO test_table (ID, Name, Email) VALUES('NULL', '$full_name' , '$email')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ID` is auto increment so you don't need to give value to id

You can write like

```
INSERT INTO test_table (ID, Name, Email) VALUES(NULL, '$full_name' , '$email')
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO test_table (Name, Email) VALUES('$full_name' , '$email')
```